# when i create directory it create at given path but it not shown in my web page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i create one web  page in that user can create directory  when user create directory it create at specified path but directory not show at user page , i tried many way but not work i need help.....
how i show created directory to user page 
in asp.net.

```
                string rootPath = "~upload";
                Directory.CreateDirectory(rootPath + "/" + txtDirName.Text);
                lblMessage.Text = "Directory created";
```

Comment: path is under your web application root dir ?

Comment: yes. actually when i create folder it store in my root dir. and i not   store my folder or any content of the my dir in DB .

Answer (score 0):

I see you're creating a new `TreeNode` but not actually adding it to the tree, using either `TreeNodeCollection.Add` if you don't care where it goes, or `TreeNodeCollection.Insert` if you do.